# how could i update integer variable with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

i found a tutorial on google which integer value could be update by using  .config(). So I had using the below code to update the value. I think my logic it wrong by put the while loop like that , but i not sure how could i update the a = a + 1 on to the gui.

My code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

master_window = tk.Tk()
master_window.geometry("250x150")
master_window.title("IntVar Example")
lab = tk.Label(master_window)
integer_variable = tk.IntVar()
integer_variable.set(2)

label = tk.Label(master_window,text="output", height=50)
label.place(x=80, y=80)
a = 25 



def update():
   my_data=integer_variable.get(a) # read the value of selected radio button
   label.config(text=str(my_data)) # Update the Label with data



while True: 
   a = a + 1 
   master_window.update()  
   master_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The setup you have so far is quite strange and your intuition that the logic is wrong is accurate.

Here's an alternative to get you started - note how I refrain from using external variables and instead use the `.set()` and `get()` operations to change the value of the `integer_variable`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

master_window = tk.Tk()
master_window.geometry("250x150")
master_window.title("IntVar Example")

integer_variable = tk.IntVar()
integer_variable.set(2)

label = tk.Label(master_window, text=integer_variable.get())
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
button = tk.Button(master_window, text="Update value", command=update)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

def update():
    curr_integer_variable_value = integer_variable.get()
    updated_integer_value = curr_integer_variable_value + 1
    integer_variable.set(updated_integer_value)
    label.config(text=str(integer_variable.get()))

master_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you . I will fix the logic again.

Comment: Use `textvariable = integer_variable` in Label and in the update function just set the value of integer_variable you don't have to config the text.

Comment: @codester_09 Absolutely correct. Yet, I opted for a more verbose approach here to help the OP understand some core concepts. As you can see I also used additional variables, e.g. `curr_integer_variable_value`. Using `textvariable` won'work if you want to set a more user-friendly value, e.g. "You have clicked the button X times".

Answer (score 0):

> how could i update integer variable with tkinter?

There are two(2) ways to do.

Either you want to start from 25 to upward or start from 1 to upward. It can be used the same script.

- Add namespace `partial`.
- Create `increment_counter` function.
- Add `IntVar()` and assign `variable`
- Add variable.set(25)

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


def increment_counter(var: int, amount: int) -> int:
   result = var.get()
   result += amount
   
   var.set(result)

 
root=tk.Tk()
variable = tk.IntVar()
variable.set(25)

tk.Button(root, width=10, text="Increase",
          command=partial(increment_counter, variable, +1),
          fg='red', bg="white").grid(column=0, row=0,
          padx=20, pady=(10,0))

tk.Label(root, width=5, height=2, textvariable=variable,
         bg="white", font="Verdana 16 bold").grid(column=0,
         row=1,padx=20, pady=10)
    

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]